# Class not available after using ClassLoader

Tags: java, classloader, urlclassloader

If I load a class from file at runtime using a URLClassLoader:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { classesUrl }, getClass().getClassLoader());
String name = fileName.replace("\\", ".").replace("/", ".").substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("."));

System.out.println("loading class " + name);
Class c = classLoader.loadClass(name);
System.out.println("loaded " + c.getCanonicalName()); // 1
```

This seems to work - output at `1` is `loaded com.robert.test.NumberUtil`.

If I then try to create an instance of that class using

```
Class.forName("com.robert.test.NumberUtil");
```

I get a `ClassNotFoundException: com.robert.test.NumberTest`. Is what I'm trying to do possible? Or do I have to use the class at `1` (i.e. use the object returned from `classLoader.loadClass()` and once it's out of scope reload it?).

Comment: can you provide more clarifications for a) Are you loading a file url, network url? b) what version of Java are you using c) At what later point do you call `Class.forName()`: a different method, a different thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around it. I was trying to compile JUnit tests, then load the generated classes, and run any classes annotated with `@RunWith(Suite.class)`, but when I tried to pass the classes to JUnitCore, the loaded classes seemed to get lost.

Anyway, because this is for a custom Ant task anyway, I used the Ant JUnitTask class, and used the canonical names of the classes to run and added the compiled test directory to the JUnitTask classpath.

Answer (score 3):

`Class.forName()` does not create a new instance of your class, it just attempts to find the `Class` object for that class.
To create a new instance, you may use newInstance() on some Class object:

```
Object something = c.newInstance(); // use proper type instead of Object!
```

This only works for instantiating classes with a default constructor; otherwise you have to use reflection to instantiate an object.

Also note that creating a new ClassLoader does not immediately affect classloading behaviour. For your example above, you had to to invoke

```
Class.forName("com.robert.test.NumberUtil", true, c); // pass explicit ClassLoader
```

To make your ClassLoader replace the current ClassLoader, you might want to say

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(c)
```